# Generar cadenas / caracteres aleatorios Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Quiero una cadena de 8 caracteres compuesta de caracteres elegidos al azar del conjunto [a-zA-Z0-9].

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de hacer esto con TypeScript?

Tengo este codigo, sin embargo cuando ejecuto mi aplicación e imprimo en pantalla, no muestra nada este es el código:

```
generaNss() {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }

    return result;
   }
```

aquí llamo el servicio y lo ejecuta

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.listPerson = this.perService.getPersonas();
    this.listSexo = this.perService.getProyectos();
    this.nSs = this.perService.generaNss();
    console.log('Listado de pers', this.listPerson );
    console.log('Proyectos: ', this.listSexo);
    console.log('esto trae', this.nSs);
  }
```

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor edita y agrega lo que llevas al momento y las dudas puntuales que tienes, te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, ya actualicé. @Aprendiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu `for` está mal construido

```
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

`length` no existe

Te dejo la función pitufando.

```js
function generaNss() {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < charactersLength; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }

    return result;
}

console.log( generaNss() );
```

Comment: Excelente, me has salvado la vida jajaja, no noté ese pequeño detalle.

Answer (score 0):

Perdonad la tardanza, aporto un par de detalles más.
Si lo que quieres es una cadena de una longitud concreta deberías indicarlo. En el código que adjuntas siempre generas una cadena de la misma longitud que la cadena de caracteres que usas como fuente.
El ejemplo siguiente genera cadenas de la longitud que indiques en el parámetro *n* al invocar la función.

```js
  public generaCadenaAleatoria(n: number): string {
    let result = '';
    const chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++){
      result += chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length));
    }
    return result;
  }
```